# How can we handle database concurrency with NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, concurrency

How can we handle database concurrency with NHibernate? How many methods does exist for this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a whole chapter in the docs about that:

[Chapter 11. Transactions And Concurrency](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/transactions.html)